# Selecting N lowest values from a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an 800 by 800 array. It is a 2d array but it maps a contour plot, meaning each position in the array represents a position on a 2d map and the value at that point is the value that appears on the map. 
For example, the point `[200, 343]` has the value `-1.2` meaning at the X-position of `200`, and the Y-position of `343`, that point will equal `-1.2`

My question is, if I am trying to take create a 1-D array of the N lowest values from this, how would I go about it?

I have tried sorting and splicing but when I try to sort it only sorts it by rows or columns, but I am trying to take the N lowest values from the entire array regardless of the value position.

Comment: Concatenate all the rows into one long list. Sort the list, then take the first N values in the list.

Comment: You can reshape your matrix into an array like so: `m.reshape([800*800])`, then you can sort it. Something like this should work: `np.sort(m.reshape([800*800])[:N])`, where `m` is your matrix

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it, i have simulated the values at `point` using function `getValue`:

```
>>> import random
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> 
>>> data = [(2,3), (3,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8), (8, 9), (9,10)]
>>> 
>>> sample = {}
>>> # Get random points value from points and store in sample to test later
>>> def getValue(x, y):
...     sample[(x, y)] = random.randint(1, 10)
...     return sample[(x, y)]
...
>>> # Get n=3 smallest points
>>> result = heapq.nsmallest(3, data, key=lambda z: getValue(z[0], z[1]))
>>>
>>> # See the Sample for expected output manually
>>> sample
{(8, 9): 8, (9, 10): 10, (6, 7): 10, (5, 6): 3, (2, 3): 8, (7, 8): 10, (3, 5): 1}
>>> # 3 smallest points
>>> result
[(3, 5), (5, 6), (2, 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((800, 800))
N = 10

# small N elements of array
small_elems = sorted(arr.ravel())[:N]

print(small_elems)
```

where `.ravel()` flattens the array, `sorted()` sorts it returning the sorted result and `[:N]` retrieves the first N elements.

The trick is to flatten the array before sorting and slicing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to take the S smallest numbers out of an N x M matrix. You can break down this matrix into a single array, by appending each array to the end of the previous one, and then sort the result.

```
matrix = [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
array = []

for e in matrix:
    array += e

assert sorted(array) == [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```